# Suggestions for free ASP.NET MVC Design Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm looking for some free ASP.NET MVC design templates for an internally facing web app. We don't have a graphic designer and I'm not good at that side of things.

Can anybody suggest some good links? All I've found so far is http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/, but there's nothing there that suits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make any html template compatible with ASP.NET MVC.  Don't limit yourself.